# Hyper activeness, simulated at work

Tags: caffeine, stimulants, alertness-level, brain-exercises, hyperactivity-hyperactive

When I'm playing games, I become very aware, maybe not the entire time, but definitely hyper.

Is there certain things I can do to simulate this at work. I'm definitely motivated, and I wouldn't say it's a complete burnout but I have trouble staying focused and actually keeping a good pace. I'll just drag all day.

I'm trying to think of ways that I could simulate the feeling at work since I can't just load up a quick game. Also I've tried playing some games on my phone like psp emulator games and something more gripping that any simple play store app. They don't really work, unless it's a particular game, for instance Dota 2. When I play that, it keeps my eyes wide open, cheeks burning red and generally gives me this feeling like I just took adderall. I wish I could find a way to always get this feeling cause it seems to only occur to me when I'm working at night. Coffee doesn't do anything for me in the morning.

Comment: I'm trying not to be judgemental here, but it sounds like you've become dependent on adrenaline to be productive (or at least _feel_ productive). Very few jobs generate a lot of adrenaline, and in those that do you'll generally find that adrenaline is actually your enemy that you have to learn to control (police, firefighting, combat soldier, etc). I'm afraid the bad news is that life is not a video game.

Comment: @CareyGregory i never said life is a video game, it's kind of a game however. Plus I answered my own question by saying it only occurs (when i'm working) at night, which means I'm more awake then, I normally play video games at night. I actually get very tired playing games during the day. Just need to go to sleep earlier.